# Troubleshooting error "Your Web browser settings do not allow you to run unsigned applications" but application is signed

Tags: internet-explorer, clickonce

One of my customers is unable to download/execute our ClickOnce application (which I'm fairly certain is signed).  I tried asking my client to follow the advice in [Clickonce , "Your Web browser settings do not allow you to run unsigned applications.!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385878/clickonce-your-web-browser-settings-do-not-allow-you-to-run-unsigned-applicat) but he said that option was grayed out, presumably due to security.

I went to my IE settings and verified that my browser does NOT allow unsigned applications to run.

1. How do I verify with certainty that my application is signed?  I've cleared the ClickOnce cache and downloaded the ClickOnce app again and I do see what I beleive is the correct "signature"
2. Assuming that the application is signed, how can we troubleshoot this issue?  I suspect this is related to the customers network.  They are a government organization, so I wouldn't be surprised that something is locked down.

> ====================================================
>
> PLATFORM VERSION INFO
>                  Windows                                          : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
>                  Common Language Runtime        : 4.0.30319.269
>                  System.Deployment.dll                  : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>                  clr.dll                                  : 4.0.30319.269 (RTMGDR.030319-2600)
>                  dfdll.dll                                : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
>                  dfshim.dll                                          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)   SOURCES
>                  Deployment url                                : http://corebeta.expertchoice.com/TTA/TeamTimeAssistant.application?t7ZqWrTkOp8xCKiP5%2f1vqG2JYPdRGxnhY%2fR5zb%2bBVDRiGg2afBaqInthrN1VxEcBFMhjr6QX%2fYMOBClnQ1X8AzBnVUeUcomt6xqm2cRv%2bs%2bWMu1dSX3SxhKs2ebeb%2fbzTS2GiU3fRqkq41Kz3RTRodFFpNc3S4dASyH9qFQ%2fzc2AhHM1DhUxiFKY5kJSjfk9k8UJEDMsRZaHSQ19Rg25gw%3d%3d
>                                                                                              Server                  : Microsoft-IIS/6.0
>                                                                                              X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET
>                  Deployment Provider url                : http://corebeta.expertchoice.com/TTA/TeamTimeAssistant.application
>                                                                                              Server                  : Microsoft-IIS/6.0
>                                                                                              X-Powered-By    : ASP.NET   ERROR SUMMARY
>                  Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>                  * Activation of http://corebeta.expertchoice.com/TTA/TeamTimeAssistant.application?t7ZqWrTkOp8xCKiP5%2f1vqG2JYPdRGxnhY%2fR5zb%2bBVDRiGg2afBaqInthrN1VxEcBFMhjr6QX%2fYMOBClnQ1X8AzBnVUeUcomt6xqm2cRv%2bs%2bWMu1dSX3SxhKs2ebeb%2fbzTS2GiU3fRqkq41Kz3RTRodFFpNc3S4dASyH9qFQ%2fzc2AhHM1DhUxiFKY5kJSjfk9k8UJEDMsRZaHSQ19Rg25gw%3d%3d
>   resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>                                  + Your Web browser settings do not allow you to run unsigned applications.   COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION
>   FAILURE SUMMARY
>                  No transaction error was detected.   WARNINGS
>                  There were no warnings during this operation.   OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
>                  * [11/19/2012 12:07:02 PM] : Activation of http://corebeta.expertchoice.com/TTA/TeamTimeAssistant.application?t7ZqWrTkOp8xCKiP5%2f1vqG2JYPdRGxnhY%2fR5zb%2bBVDRiGg2afBaqInthrN1VxEcBFMhjr6QX%2fYMOBClnQ1X8AzBnVUeUcomt6xqm2cRv%2bs%2bWMu1dSX3SxhKs2ebeb%2fbzTS2GiU3fRqkq41Kz3RTRodFFpNc3S4dASyH9qFQ%2fzc2AhHM1DhUxiFKY5kJSjfk9k8UJEDMsRZaHSQ19Rg25gw%3d%3d
>   has started.   ERROR DETAILS
>                  Following errors were detected during this operation.
>                  * [11/19/2012 12:07:03 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Manifest)
>                                  - Your Web browser settings do not allow you to run unsigned applications.
>                                  - Source: System.Deployment
>                                  - Stack trace:
>                                                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.BrowserSettings.Validate(String
>   manifestPath)
>                                                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)
>                                                at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object
>   state)   COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
>                  No transaction information is available.